# How to choose the Nth picturebox

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a memory game. I have 16 different pictureboxes(pbx1, pbx2...).

And now I am trying to make them revert to questionmarks after a wrong guess. This is what I've so far done:

```
        void questionMarker(int lastBoxCLicked)
    {
        if(lastBoxClicked == 1)
        {
            pbx1.Image = Image.FromFile("../Bilder/Frågetecken.png");
        }
        else if(lastBoxClicked == 2)
        {
            pbx2.Image = Image.FromFile("../Bilder/Frågetecken.png");
        }
        else if (lastBoxClicked == 3)
        {
            pbx3.Image = Image.FromFile("../Bilder/Frågetecken.png");
        }
        else if (lastBoxClicked == 5)
        {
            pbx4.Image = Image.FromFile("../Bilder/Frågetecken.png");
        }
    }
```

But this becomes quite tedious and horrendous to look at as I have 16 pbx'es. Is there any way to write it like this?:

```
        void questionMarker(int lastBoxClicked)
    {
        pbx[lastBoxClicked].Image = Image.FromFile("../Bilder/Frågetecken.png");
    }
```

If I put this code in it just says that there is nothing named pbx.

Comment: put them in a list, loop over it?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do, but I dont know how to. I have pbx1 but how do I write pbx[i] correctly so that I dont get any errors.

Comment: Are the pictureboxes all in the same parent control? Are those conditions all different? What you want to do, are the actions in the `if` all different?

Comment: is it the same condition for all `pbx`? or each `pbx` must satisfy its own condition?

Comment: I have rephrased my question so you better understand what I am trying to do

Comment: `pbx = new[] { pbx1, pbx2, .., pbx16 }`

Comment: use a dictionary, mapping the box number to the picturebox-control.

Comment: @KevinXVIII: I guess you have a click handler, so you have already the instance of the PictureBox that was clicked. If that's true you just need `((PictureBox)sender).Image = Image.FromFile("../Bilder/Frågetecken.png");`. Edited my answer below

Comment: The designer will give them each a different name.  Just because they have numbers in their names doesn't make them an array.  But to arrange for a quick mapping from number to control, you'll likely want to create an array and populate it with all the PictureBox controls.  Since you created them all "by hand" in the designer, you'll also have to populate the array "by hand".  You could be clever and build this index using a string that formulates the name  `string.Format("pbx{0}", n)` should be a name that matches - if you've named them as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PictureBox[] PictureBoxArray = new PictureBox[3];
```

This creates an array of 3 picture boxes called PictureBoxArray.

You can loop through like an ordinary array or access certain picture boxes using PictureBoxArray[i]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "recurse" option of `Controls.Find()`. This will find the control "by name" no matter where or how deeply nested it is on the form:

```
Image questionMark = Image.FromFile("../Bilder/Frågetecken.png");

void questionMarker(int lastBoxCLicked)
{
    PictureBox pb = this.Controls.Find("pbx" + lastBoxCLicked, true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
    if (pb != null)
    {
        pb.Image = questionMark;
    }
}
```